# Date with JS does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code taken from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zydZ2/) and modified a little:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            function DateFromString(str){ 
                str = str.split(/\D+/);
                str = new Date(str[0],str[1]-1,(parseInt(str[2])+1));
                return MMDDYYYY(str);
            }

            function MMDDYYYY(str) {
                var ndateArr = str.toString().split(' ');
                var Months = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec';
                return (parseInt(Months.indexOf(ndateArr[1])/4)+1)+'/'+ndateArr[2]+'/'+ndateArr[3];
            }

            function Add7Days() {
                var date = $('#start_date').val();
                var ndate = DateFromString(date);
                return ndate;
            }

            $('#start_date').change(function(){
                $('#end_date').val(Add7Days());
            });

        });



        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Start Date
        <input type="date" id="start_date" value=''> 
        <br>
        End date
        <input type="text" id="end_date" value=''> 
    </body> </html>
```

From [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zydZ2/), it awesomely works. But when transfered in my own sublime editor, saved it as sampledate.html, and run it in my chrome browser, it does not work. What could be the problem?

Comment: Just use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  You'll be glad you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsFiddle automatically references JQuery if you look on the left pane under Frameworks, however in your page you have to explicitly reference it.

you need to add a script reference to jquery in your head tag before your script tag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
```

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm sorry for the lack of idea about this. Now, it greatly worked. I can accept this answer in 5 mins.